# Can't log error data using winston for express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, winston

winston and winston-mongodb set up to record logs for my express app. The problem is that it is only recording logs for the endpoint that i have at my root directory such as localhost:3000/apidocs or localhost:3000/index but I have an entire REST app at localhost:3000/api/v1/customers and it is not showing any log when a request is made to any such address. The following code shows how i have set up express winston.

```
winston.add(MongoDB, {db:'logs'});

    app.use(expressWinston.logger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
          json: true,
          colorize: true
        }),
        new (winston.transports.MongoDB)(
        {
            db : 'logs',

        }
        )
      ]
    }));

    app.use(app.router);


    app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
          json: true,
          colorize: true
        }),
        new (winston.transports.MongoDB)(
        {
            db : 'logs',

        }
        )
      ]
    }));
```

Any help would be really appreciated.